# Как поменять права доступа к символической ссылке

Tags: linux, mac, terminal

Есть символическая ссылка, не могу сменить права на `755` (`chmod 755 test6`)

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 vsymonch  2017     5 Sep 18 15:26 test6 -> test0
```

Или может при создании линка `ln -s test0 test6` как-то передать права?

Comment: Нашел схожий ответ, посмотри, может поможет:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87200/change-permissions-for-a-symbolic-link<br>

Answer (score 10):

изменение прав доступа к самой символической ссылке не имеет никакого смысла.

можно считать, что их просто нет (вариант: они одинаковы для любого процесса).

манипуляции с правами доступа к символической ссылке «прозрачно транслируются» на объект файловой системы, на который она ссылается.

---

иллюстрация. создадим файл и ссылку на него:

```
$ touch файл
$ ln -s файл ссылка
$ ls -l ссылка файл
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u u 8 Sep 18 22:26 ссылка -> файл
-rw-r--r-- 1 u u 0 Sep 18 22:25 файл
```

попробуем изменить права якобы на саму ссылку (добавим три бита исполнения — для владельца, группы и остальных):

```
$ chmod a+x ссылка
```

права изменились у объекта, на который ссылается ссылка (т.е., у файла):

```
$ ls -l ссылка файл
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u u 8 Sep 18 22:26 ссылка -> файл
-rwxr-xr-x 1 u u 0 Sep 18 22:25 файл
```

проверим и удаление прав (удалим шесть битов — чтение и исполнение для владельца, группы и остальных):

```
$ chmod a-rx ссылка
$ ls -l ссылка файл 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u u 8 Sep 18 22:26 ссылка -> файл
--w------- 1 u u 0 Sep 18 22:25 файл
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего уже неактуально, но возможно кто-то, кто будет искать, тому поможет

```
chmod -h права ссылка
```

Comment: А что делает опция -h, не подскажите?

Comment: это неправильная команда.